# Is there a way to send query params for tests?

Tags: python, django, testing

I am trying to make some tests in which asks for ads of a particular type

for instance:

- `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ads/?type=normal` should return the normal ads

and

- `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ads/?type=premium` should return the premium ads

the tests ask for the ads like this `response = self.client.get(reverse("ads"))` self.client is for the site.

Reverse() was the function i have been using for the other tests so i thought it would work as fine.

i was looking for a way i could send the parameters but there is nothing on the internet as far as i'm concerned and i have been struggling with this for hours.
┻━┻ ︵ヽ(`Д´)ﾉ︵ ┻━┻

If you need any more info i could bring you

i tried using:

`reverse("ads", kwargs={"type": "normal"})`
`reverse("ads", QUERY_PARAMS={"type": "normal"})`
`reverse("ads", QUERY_KWARGS={"type": "normal"})`
`reverse("ads", {"type": "normal"})`

These are all things I found online.

However, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a URL is like `domain/search/?q=haha`, you would use `request.GET.get('q', '')`.

`q` is the parameter you want, and `''` is the default value if `q` isn't found.
However, if you are instead just configuring your URLconf**, then your captures from the regex are passed to the function as arguments (or named arguments).

Such as:

```
(r'^user/(?P<username>\w{0,50})/$', views.profile_page,),
```

Then in your views.py you would have

```
def profile_page(request, username):
    # Rest of the method
```